# Finding SQL Server on deployed PC and attaching mdf file to it with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I made this application for my school, it requires using a SQL Server database. I need to use procedures and stuff so I don't have any alternative. And I am making this application offline. I am using this connection string: (this doesn't work by the way.)

```
static string Adres = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\ÇağataySarp\\Documents\\ProjectDragonFly\\KUTUPHANE\\KUTUPHANE.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

I think I need to know the server name of user's computer but how can I know there is any server? Or how can I automatically use this information with my connection string?

I know I didn't give much but I really need your help. Thank you.

Comment: The name of server have to be on server computer but not on the user's computer. Do you have a separate database for each user?

Comment: You're really not going to have much luck connecting to a localDB instance on another machine. Your best bet is to either get a copy of SQL Express and install it somewhere everyone can access, or copy the actual .mdf file to your machine, and use your machine's localDB

Comment: I am making this application **offline**. So there is no server computer for users to connect. That would be much easier.

Comment: Well...if it is offline then you are certainly not going to be able to connect to another machine. You will need to have SQL Express installed on every machine that runs this app so you can connect to it.